# How to center border-boxes within another box?

Tags: html, css

I am an amateur coder so instead of creating a grid to organize my boxes, I decided to code individual ones (I know that isn't ideal). This is what I have for one of my boxes. I tried everything to center that 'link-box' button in the larger box, but it remains leaning to the left side. I'm pretty sure I've made a mistake somewhere with the link box.

[Image of my code, the box in the middle corresponds to the specific piece of code below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NFhU.jpg)

```html
        
   
    <!-- box two- floyd -->
    <div class="border-box" style="
    float: right;
    position: auto;   
    left:-20px; 
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: #466995;
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: -20px;">
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9c/George_Floyd.png" 
             style="width: 220px; position: center; padding-left: -5px; padding-right: -5px; 
    padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: -50px;">
     <h6 style="margin: -5px;"> George Floyd 
     <br>
      May 25th, 2020 </h6>   
     
       <!-- LINK BOX 2 -->
      <div class="border-box" style="
     position: auto;
     padding-left: -5px; 
     padding-right: -5px;
     padding-bottom: -20px;
     border: none;
     background-color: #466995;
     width: 180px;
     height: 50px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 20px;">
      <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.nytimes.com/article/george-floyd.html" 
     target="_blank">
      <h7 style="
     text-align: center;
     padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sands serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: auto;"> Click to learn more about George Floyd's story </h7> </a>
      </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: `position: auto;` - No such thing

Comment: `h7 ` No such thing

Comment: Make your `border-box` element `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to center something, there are a few ways to do it. In this case I suggest assigning `margin: 0 auto;` to your button. This tells the browser to set `0` margin on top and bottom while setting `auto` to the left and right. Here's a link: https://jsfiddle.net/jry8en71/

Here's how you might want to approach it: https://jsfiddle.net/v8d73a21/

Just a heads up, you shouldn't use negative padding. If you're an amateur there's nothing wrong with getting your hands dirty, you should check out some documentation on [responsive web design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design)

Answer (score 0):

Add

> margin:auto

to the

> ```
>   <div class="border-box"
> ```

The code snippet in my answer shows how it will look after that

```html
<!-- box two- floyd -->
    <div class="border-box" style="
    float: right;
    position: auto;   
    left:-20px; 
    border: 10px solid;
    border-color: #466995;
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: -20px;">
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9c/George_Floyd.png" 
             style="width: 220px; position: center; padding-left: -5px; padding-right: -5px; 
    padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: -50px; ">
     <h6 style="margin: -5px; margin-bottom: 20px"> George Floyd 
     <br>
      May 25th, 2020 </h6>   
     
       <!-- LINK BOX 2 -->
      <div class="border-box" style="
     position: auto;
     padding-left: -5px; 
     padding-right: -5px;
     padding-bottom: -20px;
     border: none;
     background-color: #466995;
     width: 180px;
     height: 50px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     text-align: center;
     margin: auto;">
      <a style="text-decoration: none;" href="https://www.nytimes.com/article/george-floyd.html" 
     target="_blank">
      <h7 style="
     text-align: center;
     padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sands serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: auto;"> Click to learn more about George Floyd's story </h7> </a>
      </div>
       </div>
```